# How to calculate the proportion between vw and vh in CSS

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I've been working on a website and as I'm trying to use the clip-path property in a div in order to create an arrow shape which I intend for it to be a right triangle, I'm getting this result by now:

```css
.aboutus {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    position: relative;
    background: #589AB8;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 40% 100%, 50% 50%, 60% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div id="aboutus" class="aboutus">
</div>
```

I want to know if there is a way in which I can obtain the proportion between vh and vw (vh/vw) to get to mantain the proportion of the triangle sides for any viewport, without it deformating when I change the viewport size.

Or if you have any suggestions for it to mantain the shape, I will welcome it.

Thanks

Comment: There is no relationship between vh and vw since the viewport is entirely random based on the monitor, device and window size. You will need javascript to gather the bounding box sizes.

Comment: **can you clarify** how the size (width and height ) are set in real ?  did you consider vmin or vmax too ? What real size do you expect that triangle to be ? (clip-path can take calc() function) . example a triangle taht remains the same size whatever the size of the container : 
    `clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, calc(50% - 20px) 100%, 50% calc(100% - 20px ), calc(50% + 20px)  100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);`

Answer (score 3):

The [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function mgiht help

> The `calc()` CSS function lets you perform calculations when specifying CSS property values. It can be used anywhere a `<length>`, `<frequency>`, `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<percentage>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` is allowed.

- a triangle always of 20px/30px

```css
.aboutus {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    position: relative;
    background: #589AB8;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, calc(50% - 20px) 100%, 50% calc(100% - 20px ), calc(50% + 20px)  100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div id="aboutus" class="aboutus">
</div>
```

- a triangle set from vmin

```css
.aboutus {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    position: relative;
    background: #589AB8;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, calc(50% - 10vmin) 100%, 50% calc(100% - 10vmin ), calc(50% + 10vmin)  100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div id="aboutus" class="aboutus">
</div>
```

- a triangle set from vmax

```css
.aboutus {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    position: relative;
    background: #589AB8;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, calc(50% - 5vmax) 100%, 50% calc(100% - 5vmax), calc(50% + 5vmax)  100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div id="aboutus" class="aboutus">
</div>
```

- a mix of vh/vw ?, maybe what you try to do ?

```css
.aboutus {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    position: relative;
    background: #589AB8;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, calc(50% - (5vh + 2.5vw)) 100%, 50% calc(100% - (5vh + 2.5vw)), calc(50% + (5vh + 2.5vw))  100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div id="aboutus" class="aboutus">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [the answer of @G-Cyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63701753/8620333) that I recommend you can consider the use of mask and some CSS variables to easily control the shape and maintain the proportion.

```css
.aboutus {
    --angle:45deg;
    --d:10vh;
    
    height: 50vh;
    background: #589AB8;
    margin:5px;
    --g:transparent var(--d),#fff calc(var(--d) + 1px);
    -webkit-mask:
      linear-gradient(        var(--angle) ,var(--g)) right,
      linear-gradient(calc(-1*var(--angle)),var(--g)) left ;
    -webkit-mask-size:50% 100%;
    -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
    mask:
      linear-gradient(        var(--angle) ,var(--g)) right,
      linear-gradient(calc(-1*var(--angle)),var(--g)) left ;
    mask-size:50% 100%;
    mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutus"></div>
<div class="aboutus" style="--angle:60deg;"></div>

<div class="aboutus" style="--angle:30deg;--d:30px;"></div>
```